# Troubles with ajax.Shouldnt this work?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Can you see anything that might cause this to not work?

I have a MYSQL connection, the variables are right. I have `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` inside my head. What next?

```
javascript:

function ratePost(id) {
    $.ajax({type: "POST", url: "ajax.php?action=ratePost"});
}
```

```
ajax.php?action=ratePost:

$postID = $_POST['postID'];
$rating = $_POST['rating'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO userpostratings (postID, rating) VALUES ($postID, $rating)");
```

```
<a href="#" alt="+ (Up Vote)" class="vote" onclick="ratePost('postID=<?=$post['id'] ?>', rating=<?=$post['rating']?>, <?=$post['id'] ?>);return false;" rel="nofollow" title="Up vote this post">+</a>
```

Thanks alot hope you can help a noob

Comment: Other than the very visible SQL injection you left yourself open to, what's happening that you have a problem with?

Comment: The obvious thing is that you're not actually sending any data.

Comment: use $_GET["action"] for header location variables

Comment: What's the error? Also, bit unrelated to your question, but for the safety of your site, have a read about sql injections, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 2):

it appears your ratePost needs some more parameters, as well as to make use of those parameters. Also, there seems to be a syntax error in the onclick of your link.

onclick="ratePost('postID=[id from php]', rating=[rating from php], [id from php]);return false;"

rating=[rating from php] should probably be 'rating=[rating from php]'.

```
 function ratePost(id,rating) {
    $.post("ajax.php?action=ratePost", {postID: id, rating: rating}, function(data){alert(data+" return val"); });
    } 

   <a href="#" alt="+ (Up Vote)" class="vote"  onclick="ratePost('<?=$post['id'] ?>', '<?=$post['rating'] ?>');return false;">+</a>
```

Comment: edited for you :) but yea the OP is including jQuery library and simply not using the .post functionality which boggles the mind!

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the data to the ajax call.

Here's a sample from the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: "name=John&location=Boston", // this line is important
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually posting any content to that URL, so `$postID` and `$rating` are probably null or undefined or however PHP handles that.

Here's the syntax you're probably looking for:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "ajax.php?action=ratePost",
   data: //Content Here
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

for a jquery post

```
function ratePost(idVal,ratingVal) {
$.post("ajax.php?action=ratePost", {rating: idVal, postID: ratingVal}, function(data){alert(data+" return val"); });
}

<a href="#" alt="+ (Up Vote)" class="vote" onclick="ratePost('<?php echo $post['id']; ?>','<?php echo $post['rating']; ?>');return false;" rel="nofollow" title="Up vote this post">+</a>
```